# Disable or remove some function in npm package

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, package

I am going to use a npm library and only some function are needed, how to disable or remove the function unused in the library ?

I still want to use the library, but many there are read and write function in the library but I want to enable read function and disable the write function so that the developer dont have the chance to use the write function

Comment: npm uninstall 'name package+version'

Comment: I mean I still want to use the library, but many there are read and write function in the library but I want to enable read function and disable the write function so that the developer dont have the chance to use the write function.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that the package exports a class `PackageFoo` which has methods like `getBar` and `setBar`, but you don't want users of your code to be able to call `setBar`.  Rather than passing around `PackageFoo` objects within your codebase, you can wrap it in your own class `RestrictedFoo` which only has the method `getBar`.  Internally your `RestrictedFoo` class stores an instance of `PackageFoo` which is private and you delegate all of the logic to it.

```
export class RestrictedFoo {

    private readonly _internal: PackageFoo;

    constructor(props) {
         this._internal = new PackageFoo(props);
    }

    getBar(): BarType {
        return this._internal.getBar();
    }
}
```

If we are dealing with class properties rather than methods, this approach still works but you would make use of [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) in your class.

```
    get bar(): FooType {
        return this._internal.bar;
    }
```